# If you push an object of mass $m$ with a certain constant force $F$, how would you get the velocity of an object?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Constant applied force means constant acceleration which means uniform rate increase in velocity, so how then can an object have a constant velocity if there’s a constant applied force? If the answer is that applied force equals that of kinetic friction force (zero net force), then what determines the object’s speed?

Comment: Welcome to stack exchange and please make your question clearer.

Answer (score 1):

If the object is moving with constant velocity then the forces on it are balanced : there is no net force on the object. The applied force must be opposed by at least one other force.

If the opposing force is friction, what happens is that this force is not constant, it increases with speed. This is particularly true of air resistance, which results in *terminal velocity* when an object falls through the air : the resistance force is proportional to speed through the air and gradually increases as the falling object accelerates, until the friction force equals the gravity force.

The same kind of thing happens with cars : friction forces from the road (*rolling fricion*) as well as air resistance increase with speed until they balance the thrust from the engine.

Answer (score 0):

For an object to accelerate, it needs a non-zero resultant force to act upon it. If a resultant force towards a certain direction exists, the object starts moving, precisely, accelerating towards this direction. So the velocity of the object won't stay constant. You didn't emphasise the resultant force in your question. So if you are referring to a situation in which a resultant force exists, it can never have a constant velocity.

But if you meant applying a force to an object on a rough floor, that means friction will act upon the object. In this case if you apply a force which increases constantly with time from zero the object will never start moving with even a constant velocity unless the force exceed the maximum static friction force of the surface. As soon as you exceed it, the object  starts moving and whether the object's motion is accelerated or not will be determined by the resultant of the force you apply and the kinetic friction acting upon it. On such surface an object can't keep moving without an outer force as it decelerates and stops eventually.

On a surface without friction you have to give the object an impulse to start moving with a constant velocity. Due to that impulse object accelerates within fractions of a second to possess a velocity to move with. Magnitude of this is determined by the magnitude of the impulse.

Answer (score 0):

While the object is accelerating, you are applying a force higher than the (kinetic) friction force to get it up to the speed you want.  You then ease off on the force and hold it constant at the value of the friction force to keep the object moving at a constant velocity.